# Integrating SoapUI test cases with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, soapui

I am trying to get some coverage on SonarQube using the test cases I wrote on soapUI. I tested WCF services on soapUI. Is there any way to integrate the 2 reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate your SoapUI reports to the Generic Coverage format. Support for the format is provided by [a plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) in SonarQube v <=6.1 and in the core in SonarQube v 6.2+.

The format changes slightly from the plugin to the core. The plugin's version of the format is still supported (tho deprecated) for now.

Comment: Thank you for helping !. I ll wait it out until 6.2 is released.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this since we are now on 6.7 Thanks!

Comment: This is still the supported way of doing it.